# Firebase Android get value by child key

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following database structure in Firebase:

[image: firebase structure]

I would like to retrieve all objects from "chats" if in the "users" object contains the key "user2".
Is it possible to download the data as written with no change of structure Firebase?

My actually code to get data:

```
DatabaseReference chatReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("conversationsNew");
chatReference.orderByChild("users").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Log.d("TAG", dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());
                for (DataSnapshot chat : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Log.d("TAG", chat.toString());
                    Chat chat = chat.getValue(Chat.class);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's quite possible:

```
DatabaseReference chatReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("chats");
chatReference.orderByChild("users/user1").equalTo(true).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot chat: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Log.d("TAG", chat.getKey());
                Chat chat = chat.getValue(Chat.class);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
        }
    });
```

This will print:

> chat1

**But this approach will not scale, since you'll need to add an index for each user.** To prevent this, you'll need a data structure that more closely reflects the use-case. So: if you want to show a list of the chats that the current user is in, you'll need to store precisely that: a list of the chats for each user. Alex' answer shows the most common way of storing such data.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no possibility for achieving this using your code. What can you do instead, is to change a little bit your database structure, by adding a new node like this:

```
Firebase-root
    --- users
      --- userId1
        --- userName: John
        --- chats
          --- chat1: true
```

Having this, you can query your database for getting the chats in which your user belong. To verify for existens you only need to use `exists()` method on the `dataSnapshot` object.

Hope it helps.